# Python script to read coordinate system of an input feature class?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

How to read the coordinate system of an input feature class in python script.
How we can use "Describe()" function and tool validator for that purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do lots of things with Describe() function as Calvin mentioned like spatialReference.. get more information [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000066000000).

```
import arcpy
dataset = r"c:\features.shp"
desc = arcpy.Describe(dataset)

extent = desc.extent
spatialReference = desc.spatialReference
name = desc.name
dataType = desc.dataType
```

i hope it helps you..

Comment: Thanks  Aragon !what are the parameters properties of this code in tool box, like data type,direction..

Answer (score 3):

[buried deep in the website](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/SpatialReference/000v000000p6000000/) under spatialReference (not under the stuff talking about Describe)

`arcpy.Describe(dataset).spatialReference`