# Checking spatial system reference of shapefile without opening ArcGIS or any other GIS software?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system

How could you check the spatial reference system of a shapefile without opening up ArcGIS (or any other GIS software)?

Comment: You can use arcpy in ArcGIS http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64889/python-script-to-read-coordinate-system-of-an-input-feature-class or ogrinfo / GDAL without any GUI - command line or Python shell https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your shapefile is called `roads.shp`, look for a file called `roads.prj` and open it in a text editor like Notepad.

Comment: Note that this will only obtain the **coordinate system**. A ***spatial reference***, in Esri parlance, also includes the offsets and scalefactors which define coordinate precision. This cannot be assumed to be the default, especially when  I've been near the dataset.

Comment: @Vince does that apply to shapefiles or only to grodatabase feature classes?  In any event I'll defer to your knowledge in this area so feel free to improve my answer if you think it can/should be.

Comment: Spatial references apply to all data sources in ArcGIS, even if no coordinate system has been defined. The offsets and scales apply to XY, Z, and M dimensions, are implemented by the SgShape library below ArcObjects (which is below ArcPy).